# Create an array with at least a given number of bits

Tags: c++, c, array, bitset

I use this declaration for an array which must contain a bit for every minute in a day:

```
UCHAR minutesOfDay[(60 * 24 / CHAR_BIT) + (((60 * 24) % CHAR_BIT) ? 1 : 0)];
```

However, this look pretty awful. Is there a simpler way to state the same? It can be in C or C++.

Comment: Is CHAR_BIT ever anything other than 8?

Comment: @Zack, yes it is. I saw it set to 9 on one particular architecture.

Comment: @Zack The TI C55x DSP has 16-bit bytes.

Comment: @FelixDombek I assume then that CHAR_BIT is sizeof(UCHAR) then?

Comment: @FelixDombek I would go with Bizkit's answer then, put it in a #define, maybe with a comment explaining the math and possible uchar size ramifications.  On a semi-related note, I prefer the stdint.h (int16_t, uint8_t, etc) variable type keywords because there is never any confusion about the size (e.g. uint8_t vs UCHAR).  Depending on how troublesome the conversion would be, you may want to look into it.

Comment: @Zack I know. I'm just used to Windows C programs. It looks nicer there because all the other types look like this, e.g. `DATE`, `BSTR`, `FILETIME`.

Comment: @FelixDombek You could always make defines to convert them to all uppercase if you want to keep the naming convention: typedef UINT8 uint8_t; etc.  The goal is to make clear the implementation defined sizes of ints, chars, etc.

Comment: @Zack they actually exist already and I use them for everything that's not a `UCHAR` (= `BYTE`). The standard mandates a char to be the smallest representable type, at least 8 bits, and uint8_t has exactly the same properties no matter what the platform is.

Comment: @Zack: No. `sizeof(char)` (and variants like `unsigned char`) is always guaranteed to be 1. `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char`. `sizeof` gives the number of `char`s in (the type of whatever you pass as its argument).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrap it in a macro:

```
#ifdef CHAR_BIT
    #define BIT_PER_MIN_IN_DAY ((60 * 24 / CHAR_BIT) + (((60 * 24) % CHAR_BIT) ? 1 : 0))
#else
    #error "Platform not supported"
#endif

UCHAR minutesOfDay[BIT_PER_MIN_IN_DAY];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate: use integer truncation of division.  Add 1 less than the divisor, *then* divide.

```
// location of CHAR_BIT 
#include <limits.h>

#define MINUTES_PER_DAY (24u * 60)
#define UCHAR_PER_DAY ((MINUTES_PER_DAY + CHAR_BIT - 1)/ CHAR_BIT)
UCHAR minutesOfDay[UCHAR_PER_DAY];
```

This *assumes* `UCHAR` is `unsigned char`.  To avoid that assumption:

```
#define UCHAR_PER_DAY ((MINUTES_PER_DAY + CHAR_BIT*sizeof(UCHAR) - 1) /  \
    (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(UCHAR)))
UCHAR minutesOfDay[UCHAR_PER_DAY];
```

---

Pedantically this is *not* correct had we needed some other unsigned integer type like `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.  `unsigned char`, assuming that what `UCHAR` is, cannot have padding bits.  Esoteric platforms *could* have padding bits with wider unsigned types.